# Two announcements: new "FAQ" and new "closure rules"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, user-interface, context

I want to point everybody's attention to two changes that will impact your user-experience here on Math.SE

- The first you [may have already noticed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9904/what-happened-to-our-faq): the old FAQ page has been replaced by a "help center". The announcement on [Meta.SO is posted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center). As is mentioned, this is a work in progress. If you find that the the new help center page can be improved in anyway, please either leave an answer in the post I linked to above, or open a new [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) here on Meta.Math.SE as appropriate.
- The second change will be rolled out next week: [the voting to close system is going through an overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons). Let me summarize some of the more noticeable changes here (though you should keep an eye out at the Meta.SO link above for most up-to-date information).

  - **Duplicates**: when closing a question a duplicate, you must select a question that already has an answer. (This, however, can be overridden by moderators. So flag away when necessary!)
  - **Facilitated re-opening**: previously we have relied on [meta threads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes) to reopen a closed question. Now, if the OP edits the post within five days of the closure, the question is automatically appended to the [**re-open votes** queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen).
  - **[On hold]**: In conjunction with the previous point, for the first five days after closure, the question will display as [On hold] rather than [Closed]. Functionally it is the same as the previously [closed] questions (no answers can be added etc). After the five days are up, the text will show as [closed].
  - **Not a real question** and **Not constructive**: these closure reasons will be removed and replaced by three spanking new ones

    - *unclear what you are asking*
    - *too broad*
    - *primarily opinion based*
  - **Off topic**: you can now select one of the "standard" reasons for closing a question as off-topic, or you can enter a free-form suggestion. The list of standard reasons can be edited by moderators. (Once this change rolls out, feel free to put in suggestions below for what should be our standard "off-topic" reasons.) For more details please read [this Meta.SO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169824/155238).

    <strike>As a side effect, it [appears that ordinary users will no longer be allowed to vote to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184162/155238) questions.</strike> (See [Shog9's comment below](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/two-announcements-new-faq-and-new-closure-rules?noredirect=1#comment36681_9956)) Note that perhaps one way to address this [previous meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9807/close-questions-off-topic-list-of-sites-where-question-belongs) would be to propose a  target site in the free-form field, *and* also flag for moderator attention.
  - **Too localised**: is now absorbed into off-topic, so won't be present as an option anymore.

---

*Edit (26/6/2013)* The new closure mechanisms have been rolled out. It appears that we have some "standard" closure reasons built-in, **including one for homework questions**. Please comment below if you have suggestions for the "off-topic" reasons.

Comment: There are some good things here.  New users, especially, can feel insulted when a question is "closed", but now it will merely by "on hold".

Comment: Please notice my answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9971/55235).

Comment: Please note my objections to removing "Too Localized" [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184567/183358).

Comment: Migration-voting isn't going anywhere - but as before, it'll be available *only* for the handful of sites defined as migration targets. Moderators will be able to migrate to any site (again, as before). The UI for this has changed slightly, but the functionality should remain the same.

Comment: @Shog9: ah, it appears that I misread that answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 45):

Since this will be inevitable:

Vote this up if you think **Context Missing** (see definition below) should be among our "Off topic" reasons. (And down if you think otherwise.)

(Please vote on the *idea* of having a listing such as this, and not on the exact phrasing I used below. If you think the listing is poorly phrased, you can comment below with suggestions for improvement.)

---

The proposed listing is (too long in its current state; see [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/two-announcements-new-faq-and-new-closure-rules/9958?noredirect=1#comment37366_9958) below. It should fit within 400 characters!)

> **...is missing context and/or other details**: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [our quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201). For help recognizing and resolving the issues, you are encouraged to consult [this Meta item](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959). Concretely: please provide context, which ideally includes your own work and your own thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating answers more appropriate to your experience level and targeted at your specific points of misunderstanding.

I adapted it from the [comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9407/1543), but modified it a bit since some of the language won't make sense in a notice for closing the question.

---

It appears that at roll-out, there is already a specific "off-topic" closure reason for "homework questions". This creates a certain overlap with this proposed reason above. Please comment below with your thoughts.

Comment: Perhaps "Context missing" is a bit more descriptive than "Low quality"? Also, we should consider developing/replacing the [good homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) into a "good question" thread. This change in the software is a good moment to do so.

Comment: Perhaps. Do you think "Context missing" will sufficiently capture the case of missing "your own work"?

Comment: It was merely a first suggestion. Perhaps "Context or own effort missing" is more descriptive?

Comment: I'm reluctant to touch the good homework question thread as is, since there are dangling links to it (in our FAQ and such), and we'd have to stuff the first part "Can I ask a homework question here?" somewhere. But if you have a good idea, let me know!

Comment: I see your point. Perhaps we should simply have a new question titled "How can I ask a good question" which will allow us to have a dedicated place for gathering all the community policies/conventions/pet peeves regarding questions in one place, instead of having them littered around the entire meta.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: also, it doesn't have to be so succinct. Looking at the [samples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op) maybe something like "... it is missing context and/or other details." (I can imagine interpreting "own work" as demonstrating certain "contextual details" about what the OP knows and does not know.)

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I like that idea! Let me put up a proposed faq now.

Comment: +1 ... based on @Lord_Farin's "Context missing" re-wording suggestion. ("Low quality" just seems so insulting.)

Comment: The phrasing ---"please provide context, and include your work and thoughts"--- couples a friendly *request* for context with a separate *demand* for two things: work and opinion. I might be happier with something like "Please provide context, which ideally includes your own work and/or your own thoughts on the problem." Perhaps we can also flesh-out the last sentence along these lines: "Such information helps answerers formulate responses that are appropriate to your experience level and targeted at your specific points of misunderstanding." Less demand-y, more help-us-help-you-y.

Comment: I'm strongly opposed to including "low quality" under "off-topic".  See [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184567/183358) detailing why on meta.SO

Comment: I have no problem whatsoever to answer questions (including homework) that do not show any effort as long as the question is formulated clearly and correctly and seems interesting to me.  Closing such a question will make it much harder to answer (vote to reopen etc.).  Please don't.

Comment: @WimC: making it hard to answer some questions is arguably a benefit. If bad questions are rewarded with prompt answers, there is less incentive for askers to improve their questions.

Comment: In the end, because there will now be an option to write a custom reason, the main benefit of having this listed is so that a good, friendly wording could be established, which would likely be superior to many off-the-cuff explanations.

Comment: @Blue: I've edited taking in some of your comments. Note that the post is community wiki!

Comment: I don't think edititng your post is clever if you ask people to upvote if they agree with it. The original statement in your post was different, so the upvotes do not necessarily have to be representative anymore for what people think of what you typed *after* your edits. Since this is a mathematics forum, I think we should only base ourselves on valid statistical tests ;).

Comment: @rbm The post does say "Please vote on the idea of having a listing such as this, and not on the exact phrasing I used below." (It's possible some people have not been voting in this way - I missed a similar sentence on a metapost before and had to change my vote when I eventually noticed it).

Comment: @MattPressland Good point. I guess I'm in the category of people who didn't notice that. It still can be misleading therefore though.

Comment: Regarding the clash with the homework reason, there's not too much of a problem, I think. It is good to have a way of specifically addressing homework questions. Perhaps we can evaluate after sufficiently populating the "How to ask a good question" thread.

Comment: @Carl: Making it harder to answer some questions is emphatically not a benefit to anyone who wishes to make his or her own choices about what questions to answer without ‘benefit’ of the prejudices of others.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: as long as a question is not closed, anyone is free to answer it - that's the nature of the site. I have answered questions before when I could see there were 3 close votes already. In my mind a key purpose of closing questions (rather than just downvoting) is to prevent anyone from answering them unless the closure is reversed.

Comment: @Carl: So I gather. I find the whole idea extremely offensive. Apart from duplicates and questions discovered to be from current contests and the like, you (generic) have no business imposing your prejudices to interfere with my ability to choose whether to answer a question.

Comment: @WillieWong There is a limit of 400 characters to the custom closing reasons and yours is considerably longer.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: ah, I overlooked that. That would be something that needs editing.

Comment: @Willie Would it be reasonable to drop the last sentence? Once the question is closed, the edits (should) have the first and foremost reason of reopening, i.e. _allowing_ answers again.

Comment: @Brian, several unsourced, unmotivated, copy'n'paste questions have been discovered to be from current contests only after one or more answers have been posted. I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: @Lord_Farin even with the last sentence dropped we are still over by approximately 100 characters. I need to work on the verbosity level a bit.

Comment: @Gerry: I’d **MUCH** rather presume innocence than guilt. We’re a pretty sorry bunch if we accept your approach.

Comment: @Brian, we're a pretty sorry bunch if we keep posting solutions to ongoing contest problems and entrance exams and take-home exams, and if we keep posting ready-to-submit solutions to homework problems. We are between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: @Gerry: I disagree completely. So far as I can tell, attempts to cheat on contests are mostly caught pretty quickly, and most of the contests involved seem to be primarily recreational. Cheating on entrance exams is far more significant, but also, in my experience, less common, and it’s not our business to play cop for exams that of whose existence we may not even be aware. Take-home exams are the instructors’ problem, not ours. So is homework. For that matter, if the instructor is using homework properly and paying attention to his students, it isn’t a problem at all.

Comment: @Brian, there was one recent case where a contest problem posted twice (!) in May wasn't caught for a month, and it was only ever caught because it was posted for a third time in June, that poster identifying it as a problem from a contest that closed in May. As for paying attention to ones students, this can be difficult when there are 400 of them, but I'll be happy to hear your advice on the topic (maybe somewhere else where it might be more on-topic).

Comment: @Gerry: I’d like to see a reference for that: the one like that that I remember **was** caught quite quickly, and the third posting was almost closed for the same reason.

Comment: @Brian, the third posting was http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431529/how-to-solve-this-combinatorics-problem-from-past-techgig-competition on 28 June; the prior postings were http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399909/find-total-number-of-ways-out-of-n-number-taking-k-numbers-every-m-interval on 23 May and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405305/combination-problem on 29 May.

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks; those are indeed different from the set that I had in mind, which, if I remember correctly, were from the similar codechef.com competition. I don’t see these as a serious problem or as our problem. If we spot one, by all means let us freeze the question until the contest is over, but if we miss one, enh. We are far from the only place contestants can seek outside help, and these contests are primarily recreational anyway.

Answer (score 12):

(A new answer instead of editing [Willie Wong's](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9958/43351) because of the long comment thread there.)

There has been introduced a new standard close reason:

> **This question is missing context or other details**: Please [improve the question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

This will hopefully help to prevent a lot of frustration.

Comment: What if the poster asks the question as sort of a challenge?
Or what if he thinks he does not want to spoil the users' pleasure to solve the problem?

Answer (score 11):

After some discussion among the mod team, we've come to the proposal of changing the wording of the "off-topic: missing context" close reason. We plan to update the message to:

> **This question is missing context or other details**: Please [provide additional context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959), which
>   ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our
>   community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation,
>   relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current
>   progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

This is in contrast to the prior message which was:

> **This question is missing context or other details**: Please [improve the question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Please comment if you have any remarks. (And see [Math Mod's Office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) and [Math Meta Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47540671#47540671) for further elaborations.)

Note that there is strict limit on the length (400 char.) of the message, which we attain almost exactly to the character.

---

Addition (December 4th, 2018): After some more discussion with the community (part of which can be seen by following the link to chat), we settled on the following (note the link-target changed), which is now "live."

> **This question is missing context or other details**: Please [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which
>   ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our
>   community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation,
>   relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current
>   progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86614/discussion-on-answer-by-aloizio-macedo-two-announcements-new-faq-and-new-clo).

Answer (score 5):

I propose a more informative close-reason (as an alternative to Aloizio's proposed replacement of the "missing context or other details" reason):

> **This question is missing context or research effort**: Please [provide additional details](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959), explaining why the question is valuable or important, or why you are interested in the question (source and motivation) and what specific issues you have faced in your attempts to answer it (which helps others tailor answers to address them).

Note that this is in line with the reasons given on the downvote-button.

[**Edit**: I have rephrased my proposal to avoid the "what you have tried" phrase that some users felt would generate more heat than progress. I have also rephrased it to put value in front.]

Comment: "What [have you] tried" is a source of much confusion.

Comment: @quid: I disagree. Nobody has ever disputed whether a question includes the asker's "thoughts and attempts" or not. All the disputes have instead been about how much is needed. Furthermore, the linked meta post goes into extremely great detail on what exactly "what you have tried" means, under "Include your work".

Comment: I'll copy a comment from chat "the issue with it is that it builds the entire process around questions that are mostly poor. To stay with the sand-pearls image. We explain to users how they should at least put sand into boxes rather than simply dumping it, instead of explaining that we do not really want sand all that much to begin with. In the process the notion that we do not really want the sand (even in boxes) gets lost. To counter this is the point."

Comment: There is no obligation to include "work" as such. It is just one form of context, often not the most useful one, but the *easiest* one to provide *for the asker.* This is why it is often put to the fore-front. But over time this lead to the misconception that it is mostly the effort of the asker that is relevant. It is not. It is a last-resort thing, and a compromise, that we even factor this in.

Comment: @quid: At least, you'd have to admit that your first comment was wrong. And as I made extremely clear in my post, what I wrote is in line with the reasons given on the downvote button: "does not show any research effort". Also, as I pointed out in chat, you need to notice the "or".

Comment: What? That "What [have you] tied" is a source of much confusion? That's a fact. That there is no disagreement about some post not containing any work is orthogonal.

Comment: @quid: Then I don't get why your comment is relevant to my proposal. There is already a parenthetical explanation of what "what you have tried" means, and unless you provide evidence that my specific phrasing is a source of confusion, it is irrelevant whether others' phrasing is confusing. Also, you haven't responded concerning the fact that my proposal has an "or", so your comment that there is no obligation to include "work" is also irrelevant.

Comment: It is an empirical fact that people get hung up on this and based on it ridicule the entire process. Arguments of the form it says "or" and not "and" are too subtle to be useful for the purpose at hand. Anyway, I don't have a keen interest to discuss the new color of the bike shed for still longer.

Comment: @quid: It's fine if you object to my proposal because "or" is too subtle. It's not fine in my opinion to object to it based on 'reasons' that don't actually apply. In particular, where is the empirical evidence that people get hung up on the meaning of **my specific phrasing including the parenthesis**? I've used it quite a number of times before and never had any contention over the phrase.

Comment: Sorry if you don't want to discuss further, but I'm trying to make my point clear since it's apparently not being understood.

Comment: You use a formulation "what have you tried" (alright the words are inverted) that  I find specifically problematic due to the way it is and was (over-)used. I am strictly against this particular formulation. Not each use of it is problematic, but the (over-)use of it is annoying, and this surely would not be helped by putting it into the close reason.

Comment: Are you really proposing another "close-reason", as you say? That would seem a bit much to me. Or are you just proposing a change in the wording in contrast to [Aloizio's post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/two-announcements-new-faq-and-new-closure-rules/29355#29355)?

Comment: @MarkMcClure: I am proposing an alternative change in wording for the lacking-context close-reason, instead of Aloizio's proposal. There are a number of reasons why I do not think Aloizio's proposal is very good.