# Additional close reason

Tags: support, close-reasons

In this thread: [Two announcements: new "FAQ" and new "closure rules"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/two-announcements-new-faq-and-new-closure-rules/9958#9958) we had strong agreement for an additional reason in the "close" dialog box. Please add this reason to the dialog.

Comment: Carl: Sorry I've been a bit behind on this. But can you (or someone else) help trim the text a little? As I mentioned in that answer we have only 400 characters to work with. It would be a great help to me if someone else can look over the text and distill it so it is more concise. Thanks.

Comment: @Willie Wong: I have now created a community wiki answer for that purpose.

Comment: To anyone who happens to read this: it would also help if we can flesh out http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959 a bit. (But no rush; the "context" part of that post is already in a decent state.)

Comment: Thanks @Carl for the CW.

Comment: @Willie Wong: ping

Answer (score 7):

**...is missing context or other details**: Please [improve the question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Here is a community wiki post. I took the text from http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/two-announcements-new-faq-and-new-closure-rules/9958#9958 and shortened it while trying to keep the same general concept.  Please feel free to edit it. The link goes to "How to ask a good question". I think there is benefit to having only one link, and making it count for inexperienced users.

Comment: There is something about the last sentence that I don't quite like: "*This information helps others write answers appropriate to your experience level and targeted at your specific areas of misunderstanding.*" Would it be more clear if one wrote something along the lines of: "This information helps others write answers appropriate to your experience level and helps them target your specific areas of misunderstanding."?

Comment: @Thomas: I edited a bit. I don't think it is fair to assume that questions must come from a "misunderstanding". (Right now it is 378 characters... looking good lengthwise.)

Comment: @WillieWong: Would it be possible then to insert *helps* here: "This information helps others identify where you run into a problem and $\color{red}{\text{helps}}$ write answers appropriate to your experience level."?

Comment: @Thomas: that would destroy the [parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_%28grammar%29). At the very least you have to insert "helps others" instead of just "helps".

Comment: @WillieWong: I am not claiming to be good at English, but I just think that the sentence sounds a bit strange. I think my problem is that for people with a very bad short term memory it sounds like "you run into a problem and write". So, it sounds like the "you" is going the writing. Does that make sense? Would it be acceptable with "help them"?

Comment: @Thomas: ahh, I see. Thanks. How about now?

Comment: @WillieWong: That's great.